# Have Matlab search a textfile of Key/Value pairs and replace the Values

Tags: matlab, file, text-files

So I'm pretty new to Matlab, and I'm currently writing a program that will automatically go through various configuration settings for an external device. The part where I'm stuck on right now is actually the Matlab process for finding a string within a file, and replacing a value afterwards.

I do know for certain both the Key name, and the format in which each key/value pair will be written

as an example of what the file would look like...

```
[Device Config File Heading]
A=YES;
B=383.90;
C=OFF;
...
Z=ICR;
```

The line # for each key may not be guranteed, so for now I'm only interested in searching specifically for the Key, and inserting a new Value inbetween the " = " and the " ; "

So say I want to set B's value to 200, such that

```
[Device Config File Heading]
A=YES;
B=200;
C=OFF;
...
Z=ICR;
```

What would be the process for doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fileread to read in the file. Use replaceBetween(str,"B=",";",newValue) to replace the file. Then use fprintf to write it back out to file.

This requires >= R2016b.